# as3 store an external variable and keep it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, traffic

I dont know if this is possible, but i have an  SWF file which i want it to get  info from an xml file only one time and then store it(keep it) there until a "newer" data will push into it

I know it sounds stupid but maybe there is a solution i don't know of...

1) i don't want to load the xml every time because of loads of traffic we have(a lot...will  cost a lot to refresh everytime from amazon s3)

but how do we get a newer data without checking the external xml file?

2) if there was a way to broadcast(to "ping") to the swf that an update of the xml is ready to load....

if anything i believe there should be an AS3 script for that.

thanks!

Comment: Maybe Shared Object could be useful for you, http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Comment: but how can i know if the xml changed to pick up newer data?

Comment: Is there a reason this wouldn't be handled by the browser's cache?

Comment: yes, for keeping one offer which is permanent its OK, but how will the swf kno when i have changed the xml?   i know that if i send a call for the xml everytime it will know, but is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

> but how do we get a newer data without checking the external xml file?

You could implement data file versioning. For example: `urlToXmlData + "?version=" + myCurrentVesion` As soon you ship new version of the application with extended data, it will work. It's global solution, so every new version of your product will work with latest data.

As for `ping`, you could create update strategy, for example: link is valid for 1 day. Idea is the same, concatenate stuff to the link, so browser will evaluate it as new: `urlToXmlData + "?stamp=" + timestampForToday` Tomorrow will be another timestamp, and browser will download updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Use second xml which will contain the version first xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't get the real subject.

You can't update a flash project without using any external update platform.

Because you cannot save all new XML data to a shared object because of "limitation of mb per data", so, flash going to delete all loaded data when application closed.

You cannot make a "permament update" in flash for "big files"...

BUT

You can update your main swf file with "EMBEDDED XML" files. Only that keeps your data updated when application is closed.

BUT that's not enough alone, also you need a "PRE-CHECK for Version of SWF" file, and that's what you can't do alone. You need a web platform featuring that way.

Mochi's "Live Updates" was offering that, but i couldn't make it work. But mochi is shutdown now... So forget about it...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your XML is BIG and you want to save trafic.
But how about small calls ?

You can have a call just to get the MD5 of your xml which is stored on the server.
Something like:  myserver.com/getMD5

Once the server will return you a different md5 than the one you have already stored, then you reload xml and save new MD5.